# Error undefined reference to `BP::Device::Create(std::string const&)'

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have a file.cpp which i'm porting to linux from windows. I've changed all the specific headers and functions, but I still got this error. here's my code.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES 1
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "BioPlux.h"

#define BUF_SIZ 1000

static struct termios initial_settings, new_settings;
static int peek_character = -1;

int kbhit();

int kbhit()
{
    char ch;
    int nread;

    if(peek_character != -1)
        return 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    nread = read(0,&ch,1);
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);

    if(nread == 1) {
        peek_character = ch;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   BP::Device::Frame frames[BUF_SIZ];

   FILE *f = fopen("teste.txt", "w");

   BP::Device *dev = NULL;

   try
   {
      // decomment next block to search for bioPlux devices
      /*
      std::vector<std::string> devs;
      BP::Device::FindDevices(devs);
      fprintf(f, "FindDevices: %d\n", devs.size());
      for(int i=0; i < devs.size(); i++)
          fprintf(f, "%s\n", devs[i].c_str());
      */

      dev = BP::Device::Create("00:07:80:40:DD:D8");  // put here the MAC address of your device

      std::string str;
      dev->GetDescription(str);
      printf("Description: %s\n", str.c_str());
      fprintf(f, "# Description: %s\n", str.c_str());

      dev->SetDOut(true); // put the digital output at HIGH - useless

      dev->BeginAcq(); // 1000 Hz, 12 bits, 6/8 channels
      //dev->BeginAcq(1000, 0x01, 12); // 1000 Hz, 12 bits, channel 1 only

      //for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) // total 10 seconds
      while(!kbhit())
      {
         dev->GetFrames(BUF_SIZ, frames); // block for 1 sec
         putchar('*');
         for(int i=0; i < BUF_SIZ; i++) // while the data to file
         {
            fprintf(f, "%i", frames[i].seq);
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
               fprintf(f, "\t%i", frames[i].an_in[j]);
            fputc('\n', f);
         }
      }      

      dev->EndAcq();
   } // end try

   catch (BP::Err err)
   {
      char const *typ;
      switch(err.GetType())
      {
      case BP::Err::TYP_ERROR:
         typ = "Error";
         break;
      case BP::Err::TYP_NOTIFICATION:
         typ = "Notification";
         break;
      }
      printf("Error: %d Type: %s - %s\n", err.code, typ, err.GetDescription());
   }

   if (dev) delete dev;
    fclose(f);
   return 0;
}
```

this is the file.cpp which includes the following header above. The class is defined in here.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef unsigned char    BYTE;
typedef unsigned short   WORD;

#ifndef _BIOPLUXHEADER_
#define _BIOPLUXHEADER_

namespace BP
{
   class Device
   {
   public:
      struct Frame
      {
         BYTE  seq;
         bool  dig_in;
         WORD  an_in[8];
      };

      static void    FindDevices(std::vector<std::string> &devs);
      static Device* Create(const std::string &port);

      virtual void   GetDescription(std::string &str)=0;
      virtual void   BeginAcq(void)=0;
      virtual void   BeginAcq(int freq, BYTE chmask, BYTE nbits)=0;
      virtual void   GetFrames(int nframes, Frame *frames)=0;
      virtual void   SetDOut(bool dout)=0;
      virtual void   EndAcq(void)=0;
      virtual        ~Device() {}
   };

   class Err
   {
   public:
      enum Code {
         // Notifications
           //BT_AUTHENTICATION,
           BT_ADDRESS = 1,
           BT_ADAPTER_NOT_FOUND,
           BT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND,
           CONTACTING_DEVICE,
           PORT_COULD_NOT_BE_OPENED,
         // Errors
           PORT_INITIALIZATION,
           //FIRMWARE_NOT_SUPPORTED,
           DEVICE_NOT_IDLE,
           DEVICE_NOT_IN_ACQUISITION_MODE,
           PORT_COULD_NOT_BE_CLOSED,
           BT_DEVICE_NOT_PAIRED,
         INVALID_PARAMETER,
         FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED
      } code;

      enum Type {
         TYP_ERROR,
         TYP_NOTIFICATION
      };

      Err(Code c) : code(c) {}
      Type        GetType(void);
      const char* GetDescription(void);
   };
}

#endif
```

this is an outpu from the compilation try:

```
samuelpedro@ubuntu:~/Desktop/bioPlux API/C++$ g++ -o bttest_simple bttest_simple.cpp -lbluetooth BioPlux.lib
/tmp/cccJUI8I.o: In function `main':
bttest_simple.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `BP::Device::Create(std::string const&)'
bttest_simple.cpp:(.text+0x426): undefined reference to `BP::Err::GetType()'
bttest_simple.cpp:(.text+0x459): undefined reference to `BP::Err::GetDescription()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: At what point do you get this error? When linking or when compiling?

Comment: I see no definition for `BP::Device::Create` and you are also trying to call functions marked pure virtual like `dev->GetDescription(str);`.

Comment: @TimoGeusch: The error says `undefined reference`, this is always a linker error.

Comment: I'm a little lost, because this is for windows and i've never worked with visual studio. also I have a BioPlux.lib. am I suppose to use it when compiling like this? `g++ -o bttest_simple bttest_simple.cpp -BioPlux.h`

Comment: Yes, as my answer suggests, that's probably defined in that library.  You'll need to add it to your link.

Comment: What?  Are you using GCC or Visual Studio?

Comment: gcc. the file is supposed to be for VS but i'm trying to port it to linux using gcc

Comment: using the compile code as above, 

`/tmp/ccKXoddN.o: In function `main':
bttest_simple.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `BP::Device::Create(std::string const&)'
bttest_simple.cpp:(.text+0x426): undefined reference to `BP::Err::GetType()'
bttest_simple.cpp:(.text+0x459): undefined reference to `BP::Err::GetDescription()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `class BP::Device` contains a declaration of a method named `Create()`, but no code for it, so it has to be defined in some source file somewhere.  Does your Windows build include a source file with its definition?  Because your link apparently does not include that file, if it exists.  If you're using Visual Studio, you'll have to add that file to your project, or else add a library that includes it.

Comment: I'm a little lost, because this is for windows and i've never worked with visual studio. also I have a BioPlux.lib. am I suppose to use it when compiling like this? `g++ -o bttest_simple bttest_simple.cpp -BioPlux.h`

Comment: @SamuelNLP - OK, sorry, I misunderstood; thought you were porting to Windows.  It helps to actually read the 1st line of your post.  Regarding your command:  If you have a library built, you can just add that to your g++ command line in a long list of .cpp and library files, usually with a suffix `.a` on linux.  If this is anything more than a trivial program, you'll want a makefile; have you worked with those?

Comment: If you're not familiar with makefiles, you should find a nice tutorial on them.  Eventually you'll want to read http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html, but a simpler tutorial might get you started.  Try http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: And as for your question "m I suppose to use it when compiling like this? `g++ -o bttest_simple bttest_simple.cpp -BioPlux.h`" No, you don't normally list header files (BioPlux.h) on the command line.  And even if you did, the syntax you're using (`-BioPlux.h` with a dash in front of it) suggests that BioPlux.h is not a file, but an argument that you expect GCC to understand.

Comment: In which case you still shouldn't have a dash in front of it; that's a syntax that by convention denotes that it's a "switch" or "option" to the program, not a filename argument.  But the .lib suffix isn't characteristic of linux; are you porting this to linux?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to por it to linux. the header and the cpp file I think I already changed it to work on linux.